# Multiple plots in R using loop

Tags: r, loops, plot

I have two data sets. One with old observations, and one with new observations and i would like to plot these agains each other in different plot windows. I have to do several plots, but i don't know how to make the loop. I tried something like this:

```
pltName <-paste("p", 1:25, sep="")

for (i in 1:25){
pltName[i] <- qplot(dfOld[i], dfNew[i], geom = "point")
}
```

But this doesn't work.

The data frames looks something like this:

dfOld:

```
            Old1  Old2  Old3  Old4  .... Old25
            21.0   6    160   110  ....
            21.0   6    160   110 .... 
            22.8   4    108   93 ....
```

dfNew:

```
            New1  New2  New3  New4  .... New25
            22.0   5    150   180  ....
            23.0   6    162   100 .... 
            21.8   5    103   90 ....
```

Comment: You need to inistialise `pltName` as a list `pltName <- vector("list", 25)` and then use `pltName[[i]] <- ...` to assign to it.

Comment: I assume dfOld and dfNew are dataframes but what are the variables in them that you want to plot?

Comment: du you mean something like this: pltName <- vector("list", 25)

for (i in 2:26){
  pltName[[i-1]] <- plot(dfOld[,i], dfNew[,i])
}

Comment: I want to plot: plot(dfOld[i],dfNew[i]) for all i

Comment: Yes that's what I mean, but not sure why you changed your `for` loop range to `2:26`. Also, I think you mean `qplot`, not `plot`.

Comment: I changed the range, because in my dataset the first column are factors. I did it plot() with plot and qplot(), and it still doesn't seem to work

Comment: I get this error: "Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type data.frame. Defaulting to continuous". And this error: "geom_point requires the following missing aesthetics: x, y", when using qplot()

Comment: It's because you need `dfOld[, i]` instead of `dfOld[i]`. See full details below.

Answer (score 0):

Make a data.frame with one column values and second column from which source values come from.

```
library(ggplot2)

xy <- data.frame(x = runif(20), y = runif(20), source = rep(letters[1:2], each = 10))

ggplot(xy, aes(x = x, y = y, color = source)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_point()
```

Alternatively, if you want a facet for each source, try

```
ggplot(xy, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~ source)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer. Maybe I didn't explain my problem properly.

Comment: I don't want to plot in the same window. I want to make different plot windows, and store each in a "vector". Then use grid.arrange()

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the plots in a list and then use `grid.arrange` on that list

```
plots <- vector("list", length(dfOld))
p <- qplot(dfOld[, 1], dfNew[, 1], geom = "point")
for (i in seq_along(plots))
    plots[[i]] <- p %+% aes_q(x = dfOld[, i], y = dfNew[, i])
do.call(grid.arrange, plots)
```

A better way to do it is using `Map`:

```
plots <- Map(qplot, x = dfOld, y = dfNew, geom = "point")
do.call(grid.arrange, plots)
```

Comment: That helped. Now I am able to plot something. The problem is now, that the all the 25 plots are the same plot.

Comment: Yes I just noticed that too, sorry. I am not sure why this is happening will try to solve it and update the answer.

Comment: Only the last value of the loop is kept, unless you use `aes_q`. See updated answer.